# Javascript in Blank Page Address Bar

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

```
javascript: alert();
```

This will work in a page already opened like 'http://example.com' but not from a blank page.

I have a code that want user to input 'e example' on the address bar using keyword search 'e' to execute JavaScript function 'abc(example)' like that

```
javascript: search='%s';if(window.location.host=='example.com'){abc(search);}else{window.location='http://example.com/'+search};
```

so if the current domain is example.com, then it will run some ajax function in the page to reduce server load, if not then it will simply go to a page on example.com.

The script works in

- Safari everywhere
- IE, Chrome, Opera, FF Opened page
- (although ff disable JavaScript on address bar, but bookmarklet is still usable)

The script does not work in

- IE New Tab, Chrome New Tab, Opera Speeddial

it seem like in a blank page the window object is not even created so i can't set the url of it, any thought?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. I've noticed the exact same thing for a very similar reason. That is just the way things are. Only way around is to create an extension/addon.

IIRC, bookmarklets will work in Chrome's about:blank, but to use about:blank as your default new tab requires an extension.

Comment: Well, if its has to go to extension/addon.  I'd rather use http://example.com/%s to waste my bandwidth.

Comment: Sure, if that is an option for you, makes sense. Although I personally like a blank tab for Chrome in any case. BTW, if you don't mind, please accept my answer by clicking the check mark next to it.